# Is there any specific wand movement for the Patronus Charm?

Tags: harry-potter, spells, wandlore, patronus-charm

We know that some charms need exact hand movement like *Wingardium Leviosa*. Is there such specific wand movement for Patronus Charm too? I have visited the [Harry Potter Wikia](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Patronus_Charm) of Patronus Charm. It says there is a specific wand movement. Below is the image.

[image]

This hand movement is used by Luna Lovegood and some others while practicing the charm when they were part of Dumbledore's Army. Also in the movie *Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows part 2*, Severus Snape uses this specific hand movement to show his Doe Patronus to Dumbledore.

But while conjuring his first corporeal Patronus, Harry just points his wand into air and shouts *Expecto Patronum*. The spell works and his stag Patronus fends off 100+ dementors.

So, Is there any specific wand movement for *Expecto Patronum*?

Comment: connected: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/36198/do-all-spells-require-wand-movements

Comment: Films are a mess; book canon doesn't mention any; neither does the [Pottermore page](https://www.pottermore.com/explore-the-story/expecto-patronum).

Comment: Do you count video games?

Comment: @ibid books,movies and JKR's words in an interview.

Comment: @SS - The image you used comes from the video games. In general movies and games have spell movements for every spell (which will vary from film to film or from game to game), but they won't be found in anything by JKR.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### **No**.

### [When Lupin teaches Harry to do the spell](https://www.pottermore.com/book-extract-long/remus-lupin-teaches-harry-about-patronus-charm) there is no mention of hand movement at all.

But we know that some wizards can do magic even without [words](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Nonverbal_spell) or [wands](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Wandless_magic).

I would generally guess that also movements are not necessarily a part of the spell itself. It is only something that helps you to do the spell.

To cite [Pottermore](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/patronus-charm): *The majority of witches and wizards are unable to produce Patronuses and to do so is generally considered a mark of superior magical ability.*

So, as Patronus charm is very difficult it is possible, that there **is** some movement that someone made up to make this spell easier. But it is **not** mentioned in the canon.

Comment: But there is one in very good fanfic [Harry Potter and methods of rationality](http://www.hpmor.com/)