# Does casting a spell require a Wand?

Tags: harry-potter, magic, wizards, house-elves, witches

In multiple Harry Potter books/movies, there are a number of scenarios where a spell is cast or some magical event happens but the instigator did not use a wand:

- In HP1, Harry removes the glass from the Boa Constrictor's enclosure allowing it to escape and then puts it back, trapping Dudley.
- In HP3, Harry becomes angry at Aunt Marge and she then inflates and begins to float away.
- In just about every scene he's in, Dobby doesn't brandish a wand, he mainly clicks his fingers. He doesn't recite the incantations, either.

This leads us to ask - is a Wand required for magic at all?

Comment: Per [REMS answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/5127/20774) on the duplicate question; "*You can do unfocused and uncontrolled magic without a wand (for instance when Harry blows up Aunt Marge) **but to do really good spells, yes, you need a wand.**"*  -Sayeth JKR

Comment: Thanks; we did not find that answer when searching. Children are satisfied now :)

Comment: Adding more info, the domestic elfs magic isn't the same as wizards magic. They don't need wands nor incantations.